# How to use azerty controls in infinifactory?

Tags: keyboard, infinifactory

I just bought and downloaded Infinifactory on steam. I'm using the azerty keyboard layout, but the game makes me use WASD to move around, which is awkward on AZERTY.

Their [changelog for an update in January 2015](https://steamcommunity.com/games/300570/announcements/detail/126434068059223056) says:

> If you have an AZERTY keyboard, your controls will now default to something more AZERTY-friendly.

This does not seem to be the case for me.

I'm using steam on a mac running macOS 10.12.3. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: I don't know the game, but I get the feeling that you need to use the "*revert to default*" option under keybinding.

Comment: I can't find a keybindings section at all in infinifactory.